# IP design for medium sized network

Tags: networking, ip

I have been reading a lot to refresh my memory of ip design set up.  It's been years I have to go back to this because I have only had to support a small network and am very similar with setting up class C with /24 subnet.  I now need to devise a new network that will yield at least 300-400 IP addresses.  With network technology like wireless devices ( handheld, tablets, wireless printer) I want to come up with a secure network and at the same time there is less of broadcasting / traffic in the pipe.  I know the group I am setting up for expects in terms of network speed so I want to rule out factors like network broadcasting has something to do with tiding down the network. Since I want to give room for growth I would like to end up with at least 500 addresses.  So the ip range I am thinking of is 192.168.56.1 to 192.168.57.254 (Class B /23 subnet mask).  I like to know down to the details as to how these two subnets will talk to each other because that is the part I am unsure of where to configure on the firewall or switches.  The type of switches will be managed.

This is the breakdown I like to see:

192.168.56.1 - 192.168.56.254
40 static ip for network devices, printers, NAS and LAN connections

192.168.57.1 - 192.168.57.254
Wifi network

Any of your feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With a /23 subnet mask the subnet range is 192.168.56.0-192.168.57.255. That's one subnet, not two.

Comment: This is too vague; what does "a secure network" mean? VLANs and separation internally, or firewalled from the world, or other? What does "less broadcasting in the pipe" mean? Less than they have now, less than a fixed amount? Which pipe - is there a switch uplink or something? "I know what they expect in terms of network speed" - what do they expect? You can do 40 devices, some WAPs and a firewall in one 48-port switch, but you say there are "switches" - how many? What kind of firewall? You want one IP range for printers, another for WiFi, but you want a wireless printer?

Comment: And, you want 300-500 hundred devices but only 40 wired ones? Your wireless network / access point design to support 260-460 wireless devices seems like it would be more important / difficult than the wired network...

Comment: I was thinking installing firewall and  had been thinking of SonicWall TZ600 or NSA 2600.  In order to accommodate direct connection  for desktops / laptops, network devices etc; I believe we will need 2 x 48 port switches.  My subnet would be 255.255.254.0 / class B and ip range  192.168.56.1 - 192.168.57.254.  Would there be any concern for ARP broadcasting being too noisy?   What is your recommendation if I want a secure WIFI connection?